# Add lists() method in Query Builder in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, pluck

I know the fact that Laravel has removed `lists()` function and moved functions signature as `pluck()`. But, this leads to a lot of work for someone who wants to Upgrade from **Laravel 4.x to Laravel 5.4**.

Hence, I am trying to find a way to just make use of existing function i.e. `lists()` in my code and just make use of `pluck()->toArray()` when this function is called.

### **I have tried the following.**

### Method 1

```
class BaseModel extends  Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array($this->method,$args);
}

public function lists($column){
return $this->pluck($column)->toArray();
}
```

Wont work!.
 
**Reason :** This needs to be extended along with the BaseModel class. But, it already extends Eloquent Model Class.

### Method 2

Tried adding the Required function using `trait` like

***listsWorkAround.php***

```
<?php
trait listsWorkAround
{ 
  function lists($column){
    return $this->pluck($column)->toArray();
  }
}
```

***Model.php***

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Watson\Rememberable\Rememberable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

abstract class Model extends Eloquent
{
    use listsWorkAround;
    use Rememberable;
}
```

Nope ain't no success.

### Method 3

Tried adding a as `ServiceProvider` and add a `macro` function for the `Builder` Class i.e. `lists` in this case.
But, the problem is the final returned entity is a Collection no matter what as it is returned using the `__call` function of the Builder. But, the desired entity is an `Array`.

> Edit : The Code I used for Method 3

```
<?php
namespace Providers;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ListsWorkAround extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Builder::macro("lists", function ($column) {        
            return $this->pluck($column)->toArray();
        });
    }
}
```

But, as I said this would still return Collection.

Comment: Could you not just copy the original lists method and add it to your own trait?

Comment: Can you show your attempted code for Method 3?

Comment: @patricus Please review the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, this is what I ended up doing to make it work i.e. `lists()` in `Model::XXX->lists()`

> Added this in **..../config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
 ...
 ...
 \App\Providers\ListsWorkAround::class,
],
```

and this is Provider Class File.

> **ListsWorkAround.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ateeq-ahmed
 * Date: 14/4/17
 * Time: 11:25 AM
 */

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ListsWorkAround extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Builder::macro("lists", function ($column, $key = null) {
            return $this->pluck($column, $key)->all();
        });

        QueryBuilder::macro("lists", function ($column, $key = null) {
            return $this->pluck($column, $key)->all();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of making a new service provider, I've added it to ```AppServiceProvider``` and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you really wanted to you could macro `lists` into Query Builder, Eloquent Builder and Collection

Macro'ing Query Builder:

```
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::macro('lists', function ($column, $key = null) {
    return $this->pluck($column, $key)->all(); 
});


DB::table('users')->lists('email');
```

Comment: Thanks!.. This works! But, still I dont want to change `Model::XXX->lists();` to `DB::table()->XX->lists()`. Hence, I added the `macro` to Eloquent and it seems to work. Posting what I tried as answer.